# MySQL View Query optimization

Tags: php, mysql

Consider a table with following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `marks` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `marks` int(5) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Sample data could be considered as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `marks` (`id`, `name`, `subject`, `marks`) VALUES
(1, 'A', 's1', 50),
(2, 'A', 's2', 22),
(3, 'A', 's3', 33),
(4, 'A', 's4', 11),
(5, 'B', 's1', 32),
(6, 'B', 's2', 34),
(7, 'B', 's3', 56),
(8, 'B', 's4', 44),
(9, 'C', 's1', 32),
(10, 'C', 's2', 21),
(11, 'C', 's3', 65),
(12, 'C', 's4', 78);
```

**Now consider a problem to select total marks of student named 'A'.**

```
select `marks`.`name` AS `name`,sum(`marks`.`marks`) AS `total_marks` 
from `marks`
WHERE `marks`.`name`='A'
group by `marks`.`name`;
```

**An Alternate method could possibly be using views**

```
CREATE VIEW `totals`  AS  
select `marks`.`name` AS `name`,sum(`marks`.`marks`) AS `total_marks` 
from `marks` 
group by `marks`.`name` ;
```

and then use

```
select * from `total` where `total`.`name`='A'
```

**An Alternate method could also be using nested query**

```
select * 
from 
(select `marks`.`name` AS `name`,sum(`marks`.`marks`) AS `total_marks` 
from `marks` 
group by `marks`.`name`) `total` where `total`.`name`='A'
```

> **Question**: How would the computation speed vary in case of similar and much larger and compute-intensive dataset?
>
> *Using*: Php, MySQL on Xampp

Comment: In MySQL, views have limited capacity to use indexes, so generally best avoided IMO

Comment: Your first query seems like the way to go

Comment: Note that the number in parentheses after int is (almost) meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry. as you can see, I have knowingly **not indexed** the initial database itself. So comparisons based on indexes are meaningless.

Comment: @ OP... please add your first trail code as well to complete the "minimal" question requirements.. now I have assume this is an self-answering question for rep. Not a problem but be ware it triggered community to send this question to reviewing.

Comment: You can simply add `explain ` infront of your queries and see what mysql is doing. Current MySQL versions will not find the best execution plan for your 2nd/3rd query (which is to execute it like the first one, index or not) - but not for some secret sql principle, but because noone programmed this optimization into MySQL server yet. Which cumulates in Strawberrys comment of avoiding views in MySQL. Also: whatever you conclude from a situation where you intentionally do not use indexes will serve no purpose in any actual optimization (which will involve indexes before mostly everything else).

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an index on marks to start with, since you are filtering and grouping by it.

```
CREATE INDEX marks_name ON marks (name);
```